# display a pop in jsp that takes value from the same page

Tags: html, jsp, spring-mvc

I need to display a pop up from my jsp. The code is as below.

```
<form:form method="post" commandName="transactionDetails"
    align="center">
    <form:radiobutton path="plan" value="0" label="prepaid" />
    <form:radiobutton path="plan" value="1" label="postpaid" />
    <br>
    <br>Mobile Number : <br>
    <form:input path="mobile" />
    <br>

    <br>
     Operator <br>
    <form:select path="operator">
        <form:option value="Select operator">Select Operator</form:option>
        <form:option value='Aircel'>Aircel</form:option>
        <form:option value='Airtel'>Airtel</form:option>
        <form:option value='BSNL'>BSNL</form:option>
        <form:option value='Idea'>Idea</form:option>
        <form:option value='MTNL'>MTNL</form:option>
        <form:option value='MTS'>MTS</form:option>
        <form:option value='Loop Mobile'>Loop Mobile</form:option>
        <form:option value='Reliance CDMA'>Reliance CDMA</form:option>
        <form:option value='Reliance GSM'>Reliance GSM</form:option>
        <form:option value='S Tel'>S Tel</form:option>
        <form:option value='Tata DOCOMO'>Tata Docomo GSM</form:option>
        <form:option value='Tata Indicom'>Tata Docomo CDMA</form:option>
        <form:option value='Uninor'>Uninor</form:option>
        <form:option value='Videocon'>Videocon</form:option>
        <form:option value='Virgin GSM'>Virgin GSM</form:option>
        <form:option value='Virgin CDMA'>Virgin CDMA</form:option>
        <form:option value='Vodafone'>Vodafone</form:option>
        <form:option value='Cheers'>Cheers</form:option>
        <form:option value='Ping'>Ping</form:option>

    </form:select>
    <br>
    <br> Amount <br>: 
         <form:input path="amount" />





    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="submit" class="btn" value="Proceed to recharge">
```

Now when the user clicks the select operator it should display the plans that  particular operator has.
 I am using spring mvc.

similar to that of paytm..

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you read the FAQ (http://stackoverflow.com/faq)? SO works best when you have a specific problem/issue and it helps if you provide some evidence that you have researched the problem yourself and you limit the scope of you question to a specific issue. Your question looks like you are simply asking others to write your code for you. So I'd suggest you research and try to code some solutions to your problem and then update this (or delete and create a new) question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OnChange of operator call javascript function as

```
<form:select path="operator" id="operator" onChange="SelectOperator();">         
       <form:option value="Select operator">Select Operator</form:option>         
       <form:option value='Aircel'>Aircel</form:option>         
        ......
</form:select>
```

Write javascript function, which opens popup, by calling Spring Controller and passing this operator as

```
<Script language="javascript">
function SelectOperator() {
    var opr = document.getElementById("operator").value;
    window.open("NEWPOPUP","/controllerURL?operator="+opr);
}
</script>
```

Whichever page is returned from this controller, will be opened as popup.

Comment: actually it is opening in new window not in popup window !!

Comment: use something like this window.open('page2.htm', 'win1','width=600,height=500,status')

Comment: you can use JQuery popup, if you need very specific popup look